# Android TextInputEditText issue with hint

Tags: android, android-textinputedittext

i have a problem with TextInputEditText , if TextInputEditText is not empty when i click on it the hint goes in edittext , with comma - space - hint , help plssss :(

this is the code of xml

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/txtUrlServer"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Indirizzo Server:"
                        android:singleLine="true">

                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and this is the class

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.url_server_activity);

    txtInput = findViewById(R.id.txtUrlServer);
    String UrlServer = StaticClass.GetPreference(this).getString("UrlServer", "");

    btnOK = findViewById(R.id.btnUrlConferma);
    btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btnUrlAnnulla);

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(UrlServer)) {
        txtInput.setText("https://");
    } else {
        txtInput.setText(UrlServer);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this:

```
        String UrlServer = StaticClass.GetPreference(this).getString("UrlServer" + "");
```